# Whatsapp Business API Groups

Tags: api, limit, whatsapp, price

What are the restrictions for whatsapp Business API Groups.

Can I send messages all the time, or are these messages also restricted by the 24hr session time.
How many groups can I create, could I e.g. create 100 groups, 1 for every person attending some event?

Is there anywhere I can find the pricing for creating these groups?

Answer (score 2):

From [WhatsApp API FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/faq/)

Can I send any message to any user at any time?
No.

If a user contacts an enterprise, the enterprise can respond with any type of message in the next 24 hours. This type of message is free.

But if the enterprise is contacting a user before the user sends a message or after more than 24 hours have passed, the enterprise can only send a message template. This is a paid notification.

Free-form text messages and media messages will not work outside this 24 hour window. They will result in a failure callback with error 470.

How many messages per second can I send?
The maximum tested outbound message rate is 20 messages per second.